# How to do a search in the DRF only for the selected field?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I can’t understand how to do a search in the DRF only for the selected field.

The documentation on https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/ states that need to create a subclass to override the functions `get_search_fields ()`. Everything is clear with this.
It is not clear how to make a request.

If just do a search:
`http://... /api/v1/?search=keywords`

In this case, it searches for all fields specified in: 
`search_fields = ['title', 'article']`

What needs to be specified in the request in order to search in title field or article field?
`http://... /api/v1/?search=keywords..?`

Fragment of the views.py responsible for the search:

```py
from rest_framework import filters


class CustomSearchFilter(filters.SearchFilter):
    def get_search_fields(self, view, request):
        if request.query_params.get('title_only'):
            return ['title']
        elif request.query_params.get('article_only'):
            return ['article']
        return super(CustomSearchFilter, self).get_search_fields(view, request)

class MyListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    filter_backends = [CustomSearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter]
    ordering_fields = ['id', 'title', 'article']
    search_fields = ['title', 'article']

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Blog.objects.all()
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DjangoFilterBackend](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend)

Then you'll only need to specify the fields, something like this

```
class ProductList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['category', 'in_stock']
```

Then you can filter using query params like this

```
http://example.com/api/products?category=clothing&in_stock=True
```

If you need more complex filter then have a look at django-filter documentations : https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#lookup-expr

Reference : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend

Comment: You are talking about filters (filterset_fields), and I'm talking about search (search_fields).
These are two different functionalities.

Comment: How are they different in this context ?

Comment: The filter works like an exact match.

A search in another: 


By default, searches will use case-insensitive partial matches. The search parameter may contain multiple search terms, which should be whitespace and/or comma separated. If multiple search terms are used then objects will be returned in the list only if all the provided terms are matched.

The search behavior may be restricted by prepending various characters to the search_fields.

'^' Starts-with search.
'=' Exact matches.
'@' Full-text search. (Currently only supported Django's MySQL backend.)
'$' Regex search.

Comment: I agree with you, My only intention was to show you a (possible) correct path and from there you can research and find solution for your specific need. You can have a look here https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#lookup-expr

Answer (score 0):

How:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/?search=Sometitle&title_only=title_only

Why:

```
# filters.py
from rest_framework import filters


    class CustomSearchFilter(filters.SearchFilter):
        """"Dynamically change search fields based on request content."""

        def get_search_fields(self, view, request):
            """
            Search only on the title or the article body if the query parameter,
            title_only or article_only is in the request.
            """
            # request.query_params is a more correctly named synonym for request.GET
            # request.GET a dictionary-like object containing
            # all given HTTP GET parameters

            # Get the value of the "title_only" item
            # How does the querydict looks like
            # <QueryDict: {'search': ['Sometitle'], 'title_only': ['title_only']}>

            # if exist return search_fields with ['title'] only
            if request.query_params.get('title_only'):
                return ['title']
            elif request.query_params.get('article_only'):
                return ['article']
            return super(CustomSearchFilter, self).get_search_fields(view, request)
```

Links:

[query_params](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params)

[django.http.HttpRequest.GET](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET)

Comment: How is this a solution to the question? Can you elaborate it please